# Python 2.7 edit a string of characters

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I'm trying to figure out how to delete everything from a string except the square brackets

If a user enters `"Hello, my name is [lol] bob [not[really]] john[son]"` or enters `"[[[[]]][[][][]"`

If the user enters something like the first statement I want to delete everything except the brackets. I do not want to implement input validation. Cheers

**Edit: Thanks for the help guys I love you**

Comment: *delete everything except the brackets* thus nothing than the squarebrackets should remain? Or their content too?

Comment: Good job on editing your previous question to remove the "Could I also do...", and asking it as a separate question... Although I believe you originally wanted to delete everything *within* the brackets...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
s = "Hello, my name is [lol] bob [not[really]] john[son]"
s = ''.join(c for c in s if c in '[]')
print s
```

**Output:**

```
[][[]][]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `lambda` and `filter`- just another way to do it, but I find it more beautiful.

```
>>> your_input = "Hello, my name is [lol] bob [not[really]] john[son]"
>>> ''.join(filter(lambda x: x in '[]', your_input))
'[][[]][]'
```

Comment: "Python 3 users will have to instead use list(filter()) instead, if any may be looking at this answer."  No; `str.join` is perfectly happy with an iterable.  It doesn't need a materialized sequence.

Comment: @DSM You misunderstand me; it is not to do with `join()`, but the output of `filter()`. In Python 3 if you do not explicitly declare a `list`, a `filter object at <x>` is returned which of course cannot be joined as it is not a `list`- so my answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: No, I think you misunderstand `str.join`.  You say "which of course cannot be joined as it is not a list", which is false.  As I said: `str.join` is perfectly happy with an iterable.  Try it yourself.

Comment: Huh, that's weird. I didn't know `filter` objects were iterable. Thank you for enlightening me!

Comment: When you time it `lambda` and `filter` is pretty much the least efficient, no way is it the most efficient.

Comment: Which version of Python? I timed on Python 3.3 (32 bit), Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt about the answer it is worth trying a few and timing them:

```
PS C:\python33> .\python.exe lib\timeit.py -s @"
s = 'Hello, my name is [lol] bob [not[really]]  john[son]'
"@ @"
for x in frozenset(s)-frozenset('[]'):
    s = s.replace(x, '')
"@

1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.844 usec per loop

PS C:\python33> .\python.exe lib\timeit.py -s @"
s = 'Hello, my name is [lol] bob [not[really]]  john[son]'
"@ "''.join(c for c in s if c in '[]')"

100000 loops, best of 3: 4.79 usec per loop

PS C:\python33> .\python.exe lib\timeit.py -s @"
s = 'Hello, my name is [lol] bob [not[really]]  john[son]'
"@ @"
s.translate(str.maketrans('','',''.join(set(s)-set('[]'))))
"@

100000 loops, best of 3: 8.5 usec per loop

PS C:\python33> .\python.exe lib\timeit.py -s @"
s = 'Hello, my name is [lol] bob [not[really]]  john[son]'
"@ "''.join(filter(lambda x: x in '[]', s))"


100000 loops, best of 3: 9.67 usec per loop

PS C:\python33> .\python.exe lib\timeit.py -s @"
s = 'Hello, my name is [lol] bob [not[really]]  john[son]'
import re
"@ "re.sub('[^][]', '', s)"

100000 loops, best of 3: 15.9 usec per loop
```

So @guess's now deleted answer using `s.replace()` over the set of characters to remove seems to be fastest and regular expression substitution the slowest (but that's Python 3.3 and my machine, others may differ).

Also note that if you replace the setup string in all of the above with:

```
s = 'Hello, my name is [lol] bob [not[really]]  john[son]'*1000
```

Then the times I get are:

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 190 usec per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.6 msec per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.25 msec per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 8.72 msec per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 7.13 msec per loop
```

So `re.sub` scales better than the `lambda` solution, but otherwise the others stay in the same relative positions.